# Can I split one iOS app into two or more, but continue sharing the same sqlite database

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, swiftui, sqlite.swift

I have a single Health tracking app which I believe has become too complicated. Complicated both in terms of code-base as well as UI.

I would like to split it into a standalone exercise app and a standalone health metrics (bp, blood glucose, etc) app. Is it possible (or even advisable) for two iOS apps from the same "Development Team"/Author to share a single SQLite database? I think I could manage data access synchronization issues should they become a problem. I'm more concerned about data ownership and what happens when the "primary" app gets uninstalled. I can think of many "gotchas", but if there's a built-in facility for handling them (or a list of best practices), I think it would be a worth-while venture in my case.

The app syncs with my REST API and this *could* ultimately be accomplished by using the same schema in both apps and simply mirroring the apps by making all the same requests. Obviously, if I break the app into m apps, this leads to m times the amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [it is possible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_application-groups) with app groups. You will have to put your database into the container directory that is shared for the app security group. Then two apps from the same group can access the group’s container.